# Can`t install Comodo SSL certificate on Centos7 apache2

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, centos7

I have bought Comodo PositiveSSL. Now I have certificate.key and zip-archive which is contains 4 files.

```
AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt, 
COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt, 
COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt, 
my_domain_ru.crt
```

Firstly I`ve read that I have to join this files into one mySite.ca-build.

```
cat my_site_ru.crt  COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt > mySite.ca-bundle
```

Secondly I saved there files into /usr/local/ssl/my_site/.

then I go to

> /etc/httpd/conf.d/my_site_ru.conf

and added this

```
 SSLEngine On
 SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/ssl/my_site/my_site_ru.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/ssl/my_site/certificate.key
 SSLCertificateChainFile /usr/local/ssl/my_site/mySite.ca-bundle
```

but after

```
systemctl restart httpd
```

i got an error

> Bad Request Your browser sent a request that this server could not
>   understand. Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled
>   server port. Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.

if I try to open my site with https://my_domain.ru I see next

> Connection is not secure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a turned on SSL configuration on port 80, where are expected non-ssl config.

You have to have two apache configs: one for port `80`, where you will have no SSL directives and another one for port `443`, where you will have SSL turned on.

Simple example:

```
<VirtualHost IP_Address:80>
     ...Some configurations here...
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost IP_Address:443>
     SSLEngine On
     SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/ssl/my_site/my_site_ru.crt
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/ssl/my_site/certificate.key
     SSLCertificateChainFile /usr/local/ssl/my_site/mySite.ca-bundle
     ... another configuration, such as ServerName, DocumentRoot, etc. ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: If i added two virtual hosts to my_site.conf I can't restart httpd

Comment: 1) Check your logs. 2) Check your apache config with `apachectl -t` command.